# swift image picker gets several pictures

Tags: swift

i have a problem with inserting images into a CollectionView cell using an ImagePicker. The problem is, if I click on a photo which I would like to insert quickly several times, then the photo is inserted several times in different cells.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        collectionViewController?.imageArray.append(pickedImage)
        collectionViewController?.newImages.append(pickedImage)
        let guid = UUID()
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let imagePath = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("\(guid).png")
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(fixOrientation(img: pickedImage))
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: imagePath as String, contents: data, attributes: nil)
        let image = CoreDataManager.shared.createImageyObject(pfad: imagePath, date: Date(), guid: guid)
        collectionViewController?.images.append(image)

        if collectionViewController?.images.count == 1 {

            collectionViewController?.images[0].isBaseImage = true
            collectionViewController?.lastIndex = 0
        }

        collectionViewController?.update()

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have a typo someplace. Please correct? Here's what I'm reading... (1) Question - my image picker is getting more than one image. (2) I'm inserting *images* (plural) into a collection view. (3) When I click on a photo - not mention on if it's in an image picker or collection view - I wish to "insert quickly several times". (4) The result is exactly what #3 says - it is. Your code (to me) looks something like I'd expect, but you've included `fileManager.creatFile` calls and an `if count == 1` clauses. Any chance you can limit it to something that can be reproducing the issue?

Comment: The array "imageArray" is responsible for filling the cells with the images from the ImagePicker, I press now when calling the ImagePickerControllers several times in succession and then insert the image repeatedly into the array, but actually he should insert the image only once.

Answer (score 0):

Mediainfo contains image url, media url... Maybe you should cache picked imageURL (that unique) in a Set then check if imageURL that's already existed.